MarkerInfoWindow content not recomposing when var is mutated [Jetpack Compose]
I am making a Map app using Jetpack Compose in Android Studio.
Basically I am trying to edit a map marker's content with a dialog popup by calling the "editPlace" function. The var "title" will be mutated by "editPlace" with the lambda expression
{ a: String, b: String -> title = a; info.title = a; info.desc = b }, and then I want the MarkerInfoWindowContent to recompose and show the updated var "title".
What is currently happening is that MarkerInfoWindowContent continues to show the old title after the completion of the "editPlace" function. This means that either MarkerInfoWindowContent is not recomposing or it is failing to show the recomposed content for some reason.
GoogleMap(
        modifier = modifier,
        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
        }
    ) {

        val marker = _Marker(1.35, 103.87)

        drawPlace( marker )
    }

@Composable
fun drawPlace(info: _Marker) {
    var title by remember { mutableStateOf(info.title) }
    var showEdit by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    MarkerInfoWindowContent(

        state = MarkerState(position = LatLng(info.lat, info.long)),
        onInfoWindowClick = { showEdit = true },
    ) {

        Column {
            Text (
                title
            )

        }


        if( showEdit )
        {
            editPlace( info, { a: String, b: String -> title = a; info.title = a; } ) { showEdit = false }
        }
    }


}

@Composable
fun editPlace(info: _Marker, save: (String, String) -> Unit, onDismissRequest: () -> Unit ){

    var makeEdit by remember{ mutableStateOf( false ) }
    var title by remember { mutableStateOf( info.title ) }
    var desc by remember { mutableStateOf( info.desc ) }

    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismissRequest() },
        properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnClickOutside = true
        )
    ) {

        Card() {

            TextField( value = title,
                onValueChange = { title = it})

            Row() {
                TextButton(
                    onClick = {
                        makeEdit = true
                        save( title, desc )
                        onDismissRequest()
                    } ) {
                    Text("Save")
                }
        
            }
        }
    }
}

class _Marker constructor(lat: Double, long: Double, title: String = "", desc: String = ""){
    val lat = lat
    val long = long
    var desc = desc
    var title = title
}


I cannot reproduce the problem, it works fine for me, the title is correctly updated. desc won't be updated, though, but that isn't even used anywhere. Please verify that the exact example you provided actually produces the erroneous behavior you observed.

It will make it easier to find the problem if you provide example code that is complete. What I still needed to do to run this code is to create my own MarkerInfoWindowContent, LatLng, MarkerState and _Marker. Most of that isn't even relevant for the problem at hand and should be removed from your example. What remains should be provied in a minimal version that just enables the example to execute und produce the problematic behavior. In short, please provide a minimal reproducible example.

@Leviathan Thanks for your response, I have updated the code to make it more complete and removed some irrelevant lines. The problem I am facing, is that when I make an edit to the var "title" and then close the Dialog in the editPlace function, the marker in the drawPlace function does not immediately update. To update, I have to close the Marker window by clicking outside the Marker, and then re-open it. This does update the Marker's content, but I want the Marker content to update without closing and re-opening it.

Here is a video of the issue: https://vimeo.com/942912601?share=copy

It now requires me to use the third party library com.google.maps.android:maps-compose that needs an API key to run, so this doesn't work for me and isn't reproducible. If your question isn't specifically about the usage of this library, then please remove anything from your code that requires an API key that is not available to others.

Adding the video isn't helpful either: Everythig needed to reproduce the problem should be contained in the question itself, without linking to off-site resources. Also, that video can only be watched with a vimeo account which will also not be available to most users.
